# python convert attribute dictionary into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dictionary

I have the following class which allows `.`dot attribute access to keys of a `dict`,

```
class AttributeDictionary(dict, json_mixin.JsonMixin):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(AttributeDictionary, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.attr1 = []
        return obj

    def __init__(self, manager=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

        if manager:
            self.process_safe_dict = manager.dict()

    def has(self, obj_name):
        return obj_name in list(self.__dict__.keys())
```

I am wondering how to turn a `AttributeDictionary` into a python `dict`. or how to turn a list of `AttributeDictionary` into a list of python `dict`.

Comment: Since `AttributeDictionary` derives from `dict`, it **isa** dict already. Just construct a new dict? : `d = dict(attr_dict)`

Comment: Why `has()` as it does the same as the `in` operator and why is it implemented so inefficient by actually building a list?  `def has(self, obj_name): return obj_name in self` or even just `has = __contains__`.

Comment: @BlackJack like `def has(self, obj_name): has = __contains__`?

Comment: Without `def` — just binding `has` on class level to the existing `__contains__` method.